# Align an image in a SWT TableViewer

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface, tableviewer

I just found out, that its somehow impossible to align an image in a swt tableviewer. Creating a TableColumn with SWT.RIGHT (for instance) has no effect on that column if its labelprovider returns an image for it.
Question: Is there any other way to align an image instead of modifiying the image file itself and put some extra pixel into it?

Comment: Do you have an illustration (picture) of what you see as not aligned? I am not sure to visualize *exactly* what you are describing.

Comment: VonC: Use any image, provide it as Label for a TableViewer and try to apply SWT.RIGHT or .CENTER to it. The image is always align .LEFT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you're running into a limitation of the underlying platform (or something to that effect). You can have total control over what goes into the cell if you draw it yourself. There is a snippet that shows you how to do this.

[Table example snippet: draw images on right side of table item](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet230.java)

Of course, you'll also have to draw any text you want in the cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot, wayne. I guess thats the way it has to be then. Was hoping to avoid adding some custom drawing to handle image alignment. Thanks for the link.